# Which of the following are canonical covers

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

> Let R(A,B,C,D) be a schema and F = {C→A, B→C, BD→A,BC→D} be a set of functional dependencies. Which of the following are canonical covers for F:
>
> a) {C→A,B→CA,BC→D}
>
> b) {B→CAD}
>
> c) {C→A, B→CAD}
>
> d) {C→A, B→C,BC→D}
>
> e) {C→A, B→CD,D→A}
>
> f) {C→A, B→CD}

We can easily see that a) is not a canonical cover because it is redundant (we do not need B→A). The same can be said about c).

Choice e) is not good, because D→A is not in the closure of F.

Choice b) is not enough, because then we cannot derive that C→A.

Choice f) is a good one, because it isn't redundant and it logically implies everything in F.

We can also see that the functional dependencies C→A, B→C, B→D are mandatory for a canonical cover.

What about choice d)? I can see that it isn't redundant and it logically implies everything in F, but it has a smaller number of functional dependencies that choice f). This is my question: is d) a canonical cover also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case d) is not a canonical cover, since the attribute C of BC is superfluous. This can be seen if you compute B+ with respect to the three dependencies {C → A, B → C, BC → D}:

```
B+ = B
B+ = BC  (because of B → C)
B+ = BCD (because of BC → D)
```

so B+ contains D and the attribute C can be eliminated.